# How to know the layout about these points

Tags: list-manipulation, image-processing, cluster-analysis

I have such points

```
pts=Uncompress[FromCharacterCode[
  Flatten[ImageData[Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/hkAK8.png"],"Byte"]]]];
```

> `{{79.044,235.992},{94.9421,235.945},{111.087,235.922},...,,{511.07,12.0754},{527.079,11.9187},{590.997,12.0931}}`

I can show it like following

```
ListPlot[pts]
```

[image]

How to know these point have `15` rows and `32` columns?

Comment: But they only approximately have 15 rows. Of the 345 points, there are 345 unique x values.  You would need to `Round` the values to get the bins you are looking for.

Comment: @JasonB. yes, the `approximate` beat me..

Comment: I count 32 columns (you have a lone point in the lower right), and this: `Length /@ DeleteDuplicates /@ (Round[#, 1] & /@ Transpose[pts])` yields `{32, 15}`.

Comment: @corey979 Thanks, I just don't like the `1`. Because sometimes it does not just differ 1 in the same column..Such as for `pts*100`

Comment: @corey979 right, I didn't focus on comments

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's been some time since I played with image processing, so I gave it a try. (A one-liner at the end.)

```
pts = Uncompress[
   FromCharacterCode[
    Flatten[ImageData[Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/hkAK8.png"], 
      "Byte"]]]];

{x, y} = Transpose@pts;
```

And simply

```
a = ColorNegate@
  Binarize@ListPlot[Sort@x, Axes -> False, PlotStyle -> Black, 
    AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image]

```
b = ColorNegate@
  Binarize@ListPlot[Sort@y, Axes -> False, PlotStyle -> Black, 
    AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image]

Finally

```
Max /@ MorphologicalComponents /@ {a, b}
```

> {32, 15}

As it operates directly on an image, it's scaling-independent.

---

Wrapping it into a **pure function**:

```
gridDimension = 
 Max /@ MorphologicalComponents /@ (ColorNegate@Binarize@
        ListPlot[Sort@#, Axes -> False, PlotStyle -> Black, AspectRatio -> 1] & /@ Transpose@#) &
```

which works simply like

```
gridDimension@pts
```

> {32, 15}

Comment: It's.. wonderful..

Answer (score 6):

Going off of @corey979 's comment. 
A slightly more rigorous way to fix your problem with corey's comment is to use the `standard deviation`, as opposed to the arbitrary rounding of `1`.

```
    Length /@ 
 DeleteDuplicates /@ {Round[#, 
      StandardDeviation[pts][[1]]/35] & /@ 
    Transpose[
      pts][[1]], (Round[#, 
       StandardDeviation[pts][[2]]/36] & /@ 
     Transpose[pts][[2]])}
```

Note that the `35` and `36` are arbitrary, and you should modify them to whatever works best for you.

Also, this works for `a*pts`.  In other words, this method is scale invariant, as you requested.

P.S. A prettier version of the code doesn't give the correct answer, unfortunately

```
Length /@ 
 DeleteDuplicates /@ (Round[#, StandardDeviation[#]/35] & /@ 
    Transpose[pts])
```

Comment: Almost, but this gives `{32, 16}` instead of `{32, 15}`. And you just changed an arbitrary `1` into an arbitrary `35`.

Comment: While the `35` is arbitrary, it does have the benefit of being scale invariant.  Using `1` would mean you would need to replace the `1` with a more suitable number whenever you scaled pts.  You're right, I did just make up the `35`, but at least it does not need to be changed when you scale the points.

Comment: Well, nevertheless your code simply gives an incorrect answer. But it's indeed scalable, so if you can fix it, it looks like a valid, and general enough, approach.

Comment: Really going off the bend here, rounding the x and y coordinates by two different numbers seems to both give the correct answer and scale invariant.  But I have no explanation for why these two numbers work

Comment: +1. Now I like it :)

Answer (score 2):

By my count (or illogic) there are 35 columns and 15 rows.  If we assume that the points are closely (but not necessarily exactly) aligned on a grid, then there should exist for all points values $n$, $x_{min}$, $x_{max}$, and some integer $i$ such that

$$x \approx x_{min} + (x_{max}-x_{min})i/n$$

The integer value $i$ is estimated to be

```
Round[(n (x - xmin))/(xmax - xmax)]
```

$x_{min}$ and $x_{max}$ can be approximated by the min and max of the list of numbers.

Putting this altogether is the following code:

```
nMax = 100;
{xmin, xmax} = MinMax[pts[[All, 1]]];
t = Table[{n, Total[Abs[# - xmin - (xmax - xmin) Round[(n (# - xmin))/(xmax - xmin)]/n] & 
   /@ pts[[All, 1]]]}, {n, 1, nMax}];
nx = 1 + Position[t, Min[t[[All, 2]]]][[1, 1]]
(* 35 *)

nMax = 100;
{ymin, ymax} = MinMax[pts[[All, 2]]];
t = Table[{n, Total[Abs[# - ymin - (ymax - ymin) Round[(n (# - ymin))/(ymax - ymin)]/n] &
  /@ pts[[All, 2]]]}, {n, 1, nMax}];
ny = 1 + Position[t, Min[t[[All, 2]]]][[1, 1]]
(* 15 *)
```

Here is a figure showing the grid lines:

```
ListPlot[pts, PlotStyle -> Blue, 
 GridLines -> {xmin + (xmax - xmin) Range[0, nx - 1]/(nx - 1), 
   ymin + (ymax - ymin) Range[0, ny - 1]/(ny - 1)}]
```

[image: Points and grid lines]

Note that I've set `nMax` to the maximum value of the dimension that I would expect.  (And this can certainly be made more robust.  I've used `Table` to generate a list of possible values as I couldn't get `Minimize` to converge to the desired solution.)